# Unable to modify fxml elements on Stage start

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I'm working on a restaurant application. It starts with a login screen then according to the user, it starts the correct dashboard.

I'm trying to fill a label and 2 comboboxes on the dashboard on its start but I keep getting **NullPointerException** on all of them.

I followed the function using IntelliJ debugger and found out it navigates to "timepulse()" function javafx.animation.Animation and that is what returns null.

My code:

```
public class CustomerController {

    static Stage window;
    public ComboBox<TableType> tableTypeCB;
    public ComboBox<DishType> categoryCB;
    public Label nameLabel;
    private static int userID;


    private void fillOnStart(String name)
    {
        nameLabel.setText("Hello, " + name);
        tableTypeCB.getItems().addAll(RestaurantData.restaurant.getTableTypes().getTableTypes());
        categoryCB.getItems().addAll(RestaurantData.restaurant.getDishTypes().getDishTypes());
    }

    public void start(int ID,String name) throws IOException {
        userID=ID;
        window = new Stage();
        window.setTitle("Hakuna Matata Restaurant");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(CookerController.class.getResource("/restaurant/Customer-nReserv.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene (root, 1024, 720);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CustomerController.class.getResource("bootstrap3.css").toExternalForm());
        fillOnStart(name);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

start function is called when the user enters a correct username and password to start the Customer Dashboard.

**That is the error I get**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Controllers.CustomerController.fillOnStart(CustomerController.java:26)
    at Controllers.CustomerController.start(CustomerController.java:38)
    at Controllers.LoginController.validateLogin(LoginController.java:68)
    at Controllers.LoginController.lambda$login$0(LoginController.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: The `CustomerController` you call `start` for is not the same instance as the one `FXMLLoader` injects the `Node`s to